# How to calculate the area of voronoi cells in matlab

Tags: matlab, voronoi

I have voronoi cells within a square. For the voronoi cells which are at the boundaries of the square, I can not use the built in function "polyarea" as the cell has some vertex at infinity. Any suggestions is highly appreciated..

Comment: Can you do a workaround? For example remove the cells with vertices at infinity? Or set these vertices to some finite reasonable value?

Comment: Removing the cell at the boundaries would result in inaccurate calculation of the total area. Setting the infinite vertices to finite reasonable values would be more accurate, but how can i do that in matlab?....any idea

Comment: I cannot see how removing infinite vertices would result in inaccurate calculations. Keeping sigularities is usually what result in errors. And regarding setting them to a reasonable value. This is nothing matlab specific. You need to find a good way setting the outer boundaries so that you get them where you want. Usually it is good to have a defined outer boundary and find the intersections. Without a defined outer boundary there is nothing to do really, because then the problem is not well defined.